# If request body doesnt contain everything from the model - reject || Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Just wanted ask, how to deal with firebase the case that, let's say, some tricky user avoids my clientside validation and submits a form which doesnt include few elements from the model, let's say that the model is:

```
const userProps = {
   name: string,
   surname: string,
   age: number,
}
```

and user submits an object which contains only:

```
... = {
   name: 'Mark',
   age: 50,
}
```

or even he submits everything, but in wrong typeof, e.g.:

```
... = {
   name: 1234,
   surname: true,
   age: 'hey',
}
```

How to tell firebase that this specified database must be made from elements with exact type as the model `userProps`?

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with [database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Here's how you'd enforce your schema:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "true",
        ".validate": "newData.child('name').isString() && newData.child('surname').isString() && newData.child('age').isNumber()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows anyone to read anything, but writes to `/users` must contain `name`, `surname`, and `age` with the correct types. Since `write` is only defined for `users`, no other path in the database can be written to. (You could set `write` under the `rules` key to enable writes anywhere).

(Firebase will deploy the rules if you set up database with the Firebase CLI).

The database rules can enforce fairly complex schemas, so make sure to read the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

Use Security Rules. If you're using the Realtime Database, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data); for Cloud Firestore, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#secure_writes). An example for the Realtime Database:

```
{
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".validate": "newData.child('name').isString() && newData.child('surname').isString() && newData.child('age').isNumber()"
    }
  }
}
```